# Checking if a Date falls within a Range of Dates in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, date

I have an sqlite table with with 2 date columns (beginning & end). I am looking for a query that returns the date range a date falls in. e.g Checking range where 10-02-2016 falls given 2 records as follows

```
(01-02-2016  -  12-02-2016) & (13-02-2016  -  20-02-2016)
```

Clearly it falls in the first range but how do I do it in SQLITE. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is next `SQLite` requires dates to be in format `YYYY-MM-DD`. With that format you could write a simple query:

```
select * from table where yourdate between begin and end
```

If you can't change your format you should look at next sqlite functions https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Also you can try `substr` function to cotact date in needed format.